# generalized linear models, explanatory variables completely determine response

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binary-data

I am very new to stats, so I apologize for this naive question.

Say I have the following data

```
 Yi      X1 X2 X3
(5,17)    A  C  E  
(8,10)    A  C  F
(1,2)     A  D  E
(2,4)     A  D  F
(6,18)    B  C  E
(9,11)    B  C  F
(2,3)     B  D  E
(5,9)     B  D  F
```

where the $Y_i$'s are binomial response variables ($y_1=(5,17)$ means 5 heads during 17 coin tosses) and $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are binary explanatory variables.

I am thinking about modelling this data with a GLM utilizing the logit link function. The goal is, of course, to understand the effect of $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ on $Y$.

What I would like to know is whether the fact that each value of `y` is completely specified by its associated factors (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`) would make the fit & subsequent inference problematic?

Based on what I've read, to fit such model, one needs to create one dummy variable for each level of each explanatory variable, effectively making the number of variables the same as the number of observed responses $y_i$.

Comment: One option is to consider a smaller model than the model with all possible interactions in it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is this what is typically done in such situations?

Comment: Well, one common "minimal" step is to omit the highest-order interactions (if any are really present when omitted, they become confounded with the error term). The more interactions you can omit, the more d.f. for error you have, of course (which is useful), but you really don't want to omit important effects.

Comment: Makes sense! Although, after researching the topic a bit more, it seems to me that there's nothing wrong with fitting the model as is. This is not even a saturated model (in this particular case, the saturated model will have 8 parameters as there are no *replicates*, I think).

Comment: Don't you have 8 parameters as is? Or are you only fitting main effects?

Comment: I am just fitting the main effects. Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you're just fitting main effects you'll have 4 parameters and 8 observations. The other 4 degrees of freedom will be for the random component. If you fitted the three 2-way and the one 3-way interaction, that would be all 8 d.f.

Comment: Yep. This makes sense now.